# Pasar datos de un broadcastreceiver a una actividad

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy tratando de enviar datos desde BroadcastReceiver a una actividad.

en el onRecive() tengo:

```
intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

intent.putExtra("valorPasar",dato);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

en el activity tengo lo siguiente:

estoy tratando de leer la variable dato (que es enviada del broadcastreceiver) enviada dentro (y capturarla en el activity dentro del) onLocationChanged(Location location)

```
 Public void onLocationCHanged (Location location){

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String mensaje = intent.getStringExtra("valorPasar")

 }
```

el problema es que la variable mensaje no carga el valor de "valorPasar" definido en el Broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás obteniendo el mensaje de un Intent vacío al hacer `new Intent()`

Debes usar `getIntent()` que retorna el intent por el que la actividad fue llamada:

```
public void onLocationCHanged (Location location){

    Intent intencion = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intencion.getExtras();
    String mensaje  = extras.getString("valorPasar");

 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo que envíes los datos en el bundle a tu `Activity` que contiene el método `onLocationChanged()` ,

```
private String message;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mensaje = bundle.getStringExtra("valorPasar");        

}
```

al obtener el valor, puedes usarlo dentro del método `onReceive()`:

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Aquí se puede hacer uso de la variable mensaje.

  }
```