# Ayuda. De Broadcastreceiver a MainActivity

Tags: android

Buen día a la comunidad, necesito de su ayuda para resolver un problema,Soy un novato. Tengo días confundido y preguntando por este medio si lo que deseo se puede hacer. Necesito pasar un valor (state) del broadcatReceiver a el Mainactivity para después realizar otras operaciones .El método onResume del programa no cumple las características que deseo para el programa y los métodos getter tampoco me función.

Que puedo hacer. Necesito de su ayuda.

Este es el [programa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104820/ayuda-con-getter-en-android)

```
//clase MusicIntentReceiver

public int getState() {
    return state;
}
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG))
    {           
        state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

        switch (state)

        {
            case 0:

                Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "Headset is unplugged");
              ;
                break;
            case 1:
                Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "Headset is plugged");

                break;
            default:
                Utilidades.mostrarToastText(context, "I have no idea what the headset state is");


        }
    }
}
```

La clase principal

```
Clase principal


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


int state;


private MusicIntentReceiver myReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    myReceiver = new MusicIntentReceiver();


    state = myReceiver.getState();



    if (vibprueba==1) {

        txV= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textocentro);
        txV.setText("Hola pude sacar Valor");


   }

}
```

Aquí esta una nueva pregunta que realice sobre el mismo tema y no he obtenido una respuesta clara [Nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105837/enviar-entero-de-una-clase-a-un-mainactivity)

Intente también aplicar esta solución [Pasar datos de un broadcastreceiver a una actividad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78321/pasar-datos-de-un-broadcastreceiver-a-una-actividad) que se muestra en este foro, pero getIntet() me arroja el error "cannot resolve method".

Comment: Miguel, te sugiero **revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuesta

Comment: Me escuso Jorgesys porque los enlaces de la pregunta no estaba .Ahora si se entiende mejor.

Comment: Amistad usted me podría ayudar con mi duda, ahora que se entiende la pregunta.

Comment: agrega las partes escenciales de código en tu pregunta, esto para atraer más usuarios y esta misma pregunta pueda ser de utilidad a otros.

Comment: ok. repetiré nuevamente la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la MainActivity

```
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JackPlugReceiver JackPlugRec;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JackPlugRec = new JackPlugReceiver();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG");

        registerReceiver(JackPlugRec, intentFilter);

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("miMsg"));

    }


  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Mensaje");
        Log.d("XXX ", "Recibido : " + message);

      }
   };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (JackPlugRec != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(JackPlugRec);
            JackPlugRec = null;
        }
     LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }




}
```

En BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class JackPlugReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    Context c;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     c = context;

            if (!intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
                return;
            }

            boolean connectedHeadphones = (intent.getIntExtra("state", 0) == 1);
            boolean connectedMicrophone = (intent.getIntExtra("microphone", 0) == 1) && connectedHeadphones;
           // String headsetName = intent.getStringExtra("name");


                Log.v("XXX ", "onReceive");

        sendMessage();


    }

    private void sendMessage() {

         Intent intent = new Intent("miMsg");
         intent.putExtra("Mensaje", "Mensaje");
         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(c).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

En manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gustavo.broadcastreceiver">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".JackPlugReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Funcionando...Saludos.

Comment: Agregue el LocalBroadCastReceiver para enviar datos a la Activity principal.

Comment: Buen día amigo Gustavo y agradecido con usted al 100%, mi calificación no se puede ver ya que no tengo los puntos para eso. Pero mi reconocimiento y agradecimiento por su forma tan explicativa de enseñar. En  foros de electrónica donde generalmente contesto preguntas trato de ser tan explicito como usted lo hizo ahora, es decir, mas que solucionar un problema es enseñar al que pregunta. Saludos y muchas gracias  desde Venezuela.

Comment: Gracias Miguel por su comentario.

Comment: @Gustavo esta respuesta no explica nada, cual de las 2 deseas conservar,  editala y agrega más información para que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios.

Comment: Hola jorge, gracias por la info. elimine la parte que quedo incompleta por mi falta de pericia en el sitio. Proximo edito y agrego informacion a la correcta. gracias.